# Sarath Sandhya - Hindi film adaptation of the novel Manju

Tags: indian-cinema, adaptation

It is written in Wikipedia that, [*Manju*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manju_(novel)), the Malayalam novel of [MT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M._T._Vasudevan_Nair), has a [film adaption in Hindi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manju_(film)) too, named ***Sarath Sandhya***. I tried Googling to find some info regarding that. But nothing found.

- Is there such a film in Hindi?
- If yes, was it shelved or got
  released?

Answer (score 1):

There are two questions you have asked. I will try to answer both of them.

- **Firstly**, yes there was a Hindi-language adaptation of the film. It was not named "Sarath Sandhya" as mentioned in your question. The name was "Sharad Sandhya".
- **Secondly**, it was released on 1st January, 1982 but the movie got completely unnoticed.

  Here is the IMDB link for same: [Sharad Sandhya](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3509728)

Comment: IMDb gives unreliable details. Who was the director of the film? Who were the actors?

Comment: Did this answer your original question @Clicker?  If so I would upvote and accept it.

Comment: @iandotkelly Not really. That IMDb page looks unreliable!